# Can I make a Filter getFilter() method change multiple lists?

Tags: java, android

I currently have a RecyclerView with a SearchView, but the difference is that as I'm filtering the main list (ArrayList), I need to change two other separate lists (ArrayList>) as well. The two other strings do not contain the main list.

Right now, I'm able to change the main list, but I can't figure out how to return the other two lists as well.

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    filteredMainList = mainList;
                    filteredList1 = list1;
                    filteredList2 = list2;

                } else {

                    ArrayList<String> tempFilteredMain = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tempFiltered1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tempFiltered2 = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {

                        if (mainList.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            tempFilteredMain.add(mainList.get(i));
                            tempFiltered1.add(list1.get(i));
                            tempFiltered2.add(list2.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    filteredMainList = tempFilteredMain;
                    filteredList1 = tempFiltered1;
                    filteredList2 = tempFiltered2;
                }

//mainly starting here:

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredMainList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filteredMainList = (ArrayList<String>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution if you still face the problem you can [see here](https://11zon.com/android/android_searchview.php)

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        ArrayList<ItemModel> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<ItemModel>();
        // Copy the original data

        if(filter_items == null) {
            filter_items = new ArrayList<ItemModel>(arrayList);
        }

        if(constraint == null|| constraint.length() == 0) {
            results.count = filter_items.size();
            results.values = filter_items;
        } else {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < filter_items.size(); i++) {
                if(filter_items.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                    ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
                    itemModel.setName(filter_items.get(i).getName());
                    FilteredArrList.add(itemModel);
                }
            } 
            results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
            results.values = FilteredArrList;

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        arrayList = (ArrayList) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        if(arrayList.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
};
return filter;
}
```